# Web Automation and API synchronization problem?

Tags: python, synchronization, software-distribution, webautomation

I have this automation task I'm planning to work on using Python but I'm not sure on how to go about it.

I need to get data (dataframe) from a web page which is done via exporting of the data. But now, when the data is being exported it starts by sending a link to your email being used to the register on the web page. This link is a Google sheet link that contains the data. The link is then accessed via your mail, downloaded as a table, and perhaps visualized on a dashboard. Please is there a way I can make edits on the web page while these changes reflect on the already downloaded Google sheets file.

And also is there a way for it to be generally accessible without the need for a particular registered email?

I'm still brainstorming at the moment.